# How do I escape spaces in a path with Applescript?

Tags: path, escaping, applescript, filenames, space

I've written a script so I can quickly get a link to files and folders on my server. The problem is that the string I get does not escape spaces. 
Can someone tell me how to escape the spaces for '%20' ?

```
tell application "Finder"
set sel to (the POSIX path of (the selection as alias))
set sel to ((characters 10 thru -1 of sel) as string)
set sel to "afp://myserver._afpovertcp._tcp.local/" & sel
set the clipboard to sel      
end tell
```

Please help thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `text item delimiters` to find and replace characters

```
tell application "Finder" to set sel to POSIX path of (the selection as alias)
set the clipboard to "afp://myserver._afpovertcp._tcp.local/" & (my findReplace(text 10 thru -1 of sel, " ", "%20"))

on findReplace(t, toFind, toReplace)
    set {tid, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, toFind}
    set t to text items of t
    set text item delimiters to toReplace
    set t to t as text
    set text item delimiters to tid
    return t
end findReplace
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code includes 3 `encoding routines` from
https://macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-08.html

> A standard practice when creating URL's is to
>   encode special characters (high-level ASCII) and spaces to their
>   hexidecimal equivalents. For example, spaces in URL's are converted
>   to: %20

Script:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set sel to (the POSIX path of (the selection as alias))
    set sel to ((characters 10 thru -1 of sel) as string)
    set sel to "afp://myserver._afpovertcp._tcp.local/" & my encode_filepath(sel, true, false)
    set the clipboard to sel
end tell

-- this sub-routine encodes special characters in a filepath:
-- My Disk:My Folder:My File.htm
-- My%20Disk:My%20Folder:My%20File.htm
on encode_filepath(this_file, encode_URL_A, encode_URL_B)
    set this_file to this_file as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
    set the path_segments to every text item of this_file
    repeat with i from 1 to the count of the path_segments
        set this_segment to item i of the path_segments
        set item i of the path_segments to my encode_text(this_segment, encode_URL_A, encode_URL_B)
    end repeat
    set this_file to the path_segments as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return this_file
end encode_filepath

-- TEXT ENCODING: encode spaces and high-level ASCII characters (those above 127)
-- encode_URL_A = encode most of the special characters reserved for use by URLs.
on encode_text(this_text, encode_URL_A, encode_URL_B)
    set the standard_characters to "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
    set the URL_A_chars to "$+!'/?;&@=#%><{}[]\"~`^\\|*"
    set the URL_B_chars to ".-_:"
    set the acceptable_characters to the standard_characters
    if encode_URL_A is false then set the acceptable_characters to the acceptable_characters & the URL_A_chars
    if encode_URL_B is false then set the acceptable_characters to the acceptable_characters & the URL_B_chars
    set the encoded_text to ""
    repeat with this_char in this_text
        if this_char is in the acceptable_characters then
            set the encoded_text to (the encoded_text & this_char)
        else
            set the encoded_text to (the encoded_text & encode_char(this_char)) as string
        end if
    end repeat
    return the encoded_text
end encode_text

-- encoding high-ASCII characters:
on encode_char(this_char)
    set the ASCII_num to (the ASCII number this_char)
    set the hex_list to {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}
    set x to item ((ASCII_num div 16) + 1) of the hex_list
    set y to item ((ASCII_num mod 16) + 1) of the hex_list
    return ("%" & x & y) as string
end encode_char
```